# Goで[]bytesを含む構造体をbase64を使ってjson化する

Tags: json, go

Goで下のような構造体をbase64を使ってjsonにしたいと考えています。
一つ考えられるのはencoding/base64の`EncodeToString()`を使って一旦`[]byte`を文字列に直すという方法ですが、どのように`MarshalJSON`, `UnMarshalJSON()`を実装すればいいのでしょうか?

```
type Picture struct {
    Id int64
    Data []byte
    Name string
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goの`json.Marshal`は自動的に`[]byte`をBase64に変換します。

http://play.golang.org/p/9jWlQY_wo9

`json.Unmarshal`も同様にデコード先の型が`[]byte`だった場合、JSONの文字列をBase64エンコーディングとみなして自動的にデコードします。(文字列が`==`で終わっている必要あり)

http://play.golang.org/p/Auhup66_4Y

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that []byte
>   encodes as a base64-encoded string, and a nil slice encodes as the
>   null JSON object.

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Answer (score 2):

Encodeは、一旦`map[string]interface{}`にしてから`json.Marshal()`するのはどうでしょうか？

```
func MarshalJSON(p *Picture) (string, error) {
    o := map[string]interface{} {
        "id" : p.Id,
        "data" : EncodeToString(p.Data),
        "name" : p.Name,
    }        
    if b, err := json.Marchal(o) ; err == nil {
        return string(b), nil
    } else {
        return "", err
    }
}
```

Decodeはこの逆で、一旦`map[string]interface{}`として取り出してから、`Data`部分のBASE64文字列を[]byteに展開する　というのはどうでしょうか？